# SAS importing messy data

Tags: sas

I tried formatting the data so that U is only numeric while all descriptions should be under T. May i know what could i possibly do to fix it?

```
DATA data;
 infile '....csv'
        dlm=',' firstobs=2 dsd;
 format A$ B$ C$ D$ E$ F$ G$ H$ I$ J$ K$ L$ M$ N$ O$ P$ Q$ R$ S$ T$ U V W$ X$ Y$ Z$ AA$ AB$ AC$ AD$ AE$ AF$ AG$ AH$ AI$ AJ$ AK$ AL$ AM$ AN$ AO$ AP$ AQ$ AR$ AS;  
 input  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T@; 
 do _n_=1 to 24;
     input U @;
     description=catx(', ',T, U);
 end;
 input U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN AO AP AQ AR AS;
RUN;
```

Comment: Your data has 51 columns, why are you only trying to read 45 of them?

Comment: Where did the column headers A,B, ... AD, ... come from?  Did you accidentally open this CSV file with EXCEL?  Do you have the original CSV file?  Do you have access to the original data to try and re-generate a CSV file that is properly formatted from the original data?

Comment: i tried to regenerate a csv

Comment: What is the source of the file? How did you try to generate a CSV File?  Is the source a SAS dataset? Some other software?

Comment: original dataset is from Datafiniti shoe

Comment: I don't think Datafiniti shoe is a software product.  Sounds like the name of a company. Ask Datafiniti shoe to provide a version of the file that can be parsed into columns. Perhaps by using something other than comma as the delimiter?

Comment: @Tom DataFiniti is a data provider (software product, more or less).  Presumably `shoe` is referring to their 'shoe' product data.  Given their free demo uses this data, I'm guessing that's where this comes from.

Comment: Actually, @konsteinuser, are you getting this from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datafiniti/mens-shoe-prices/home)??

Comment: Either way, we shouldn't have google drive files links here - who knows what's in them - instead show an example in the question text directly as datalines.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the data file in this [Kaggle project](https://www.kaggle.com/datafiniti/mens-shoe-prices) then I would use a divide and conquer approach.  Check each line in the file to see how many columns it contains.  Then split the problem lines into separate file(s) and figure out how to handle whatever issue it is that causes them to be poorly formatted/parsed.

So get a list of the rows and number of columns in each row.

```
data maxcol;
  infile "C:\downloads\archive.zip" zip member='Datafiniti_Mens_Shoe_Prices.csv'
          dsd truncover column=cc length=ll lrecl=2000000
  ;
  row+1;
  input @;
  do maxcol=1 by 1 while(cc<=ll); input dummy :$1. @ +(-1) dummy $char1. @; end;
  if dummy ne ',' then maxcol=maxcol-1;
  keep row maxcol ;
run;

proc freq ;
 tables maxcol;
run;
```

[image]

For example you could get the list of bad row numbers into a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select row into :rowlist separated by ' ' from maxcol where maxcol > 48 ;
quit;
```

Then use that macro variable in your code that reads the datafile.

```
data want;
  infile "C:\downloads\archive.zip" zip member='Datafiniti_Mens_Shoe_Prices.csv' dsd
          truncover lrecl=2000000 
  ;
  input @;
  if _n_ in (1 &rowlist) then delete;
  ... rest of data step to read the "good" rows ...
```

For the other rows take a look at them and figure out where they are getting extra columns inserted. Possibly just fix them by hand. Or craft separate data steps to read each set separately using the same &ROWLIST trick.

### If you are positive that

- the extra columns are inserted between column 20 and 21
- that column 21 always has a valid numeric string
- none of the extra values are valid numeric strings

then you could use logic like this to generate a new delimited file (why not use `|` as the delimiter this time?).

```
data _null_;
  infile "C:\downloads\archive.zip" zip member='Datafiniti_Mens_Shoe_Prices.csv' dsd
          truncover lrecl=2000000
  ;
  row+1;
  length col1-col48 $32767;
  input col1-col21 @;
  if _N_>1 then do while(missing(input(col21,??32.)));
     col20=catx(',',col20,col21);
     input col21 @;
  end;
  input col22-col48;
  file "c:\downloads\shoes.txt" dsd dlm='|' lrecl=2000000 ;
  put col1-col48 ;
run;
```

Which you could even then try to read using PROC IMPORT to guess how to define the variables. (But watch out as PROC IMPORT might truncate some of the records by using LRECL=32767)

```
proc import datafile="c:\downloads\shoes.txt" dbms=csv out=want replace ;
  delimiter='|';
  guessingrows=max;
run;
```

Checking column 21:

```
The MEANS Procedure

                Analysis Variable : prices_amountMin

    N            Mean         Std Dev         Minimum         Maximum
---------------------------------------------------------------------
19387     111.8138820     276.7080893               0        16949.00
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. what is meant by column=cc?

Comment: COLUMN= option sets the name of  a variable that will contain the current value of the column pointer.  Just like the LENGTH= option is used to name a variable that contains the length of the current line.

Comment: could you explain how maxcol works (the first chunk of code)?

Comment: It reads fields from the line until it has read past the end of the line.  Each time it reads a field it re-reads the character before the start of the field it will read next.  This is so it can adjust the count for the extra time thru the DO loop when the last field is not empty.

Comment: I tired to just delete all price_min columns that is non-numeric with if not (anyalpha(price_min)) then delete; in data statement but that didnt work. I also wish to read the Json values in merchants, may i know can i start?

Comment: How did you get values into a PRICE_MIN variable to delete them?  If you cannot parse the lines into columns than what is the PRICE_MIN variable going to contain?  Parsing JSON is a different question than parsing a delimited file you can ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks i think i post a new question with my codes